# submit form with button outside form using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I try to post a form using ajax the current code does not really work. When I press the save button the form get submitted n + 1 times. i.e After refreshing the page it submit once, next time I submit two form get submitted, third time... etc.

I have spend a lot of time researching this already (2 days) and I have not found a questions quite similar to what I am asking.

I am on a steep learning curve here so I hope someone can point out to me what I am doing wrong.

I think I might have mixed something up. The steps up to submit is.

1. Form values is being filled in.
2. A button is pressed to show a modal to confirm to submit the form (The submit button is actually inside this modal and not inside the form itself).
3. Form is submitted.

```js
$('#confirmYes').click(function() {
  $('#confirm-object').modal('hide'); // close confirm modal
  $('#newForm').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let formData = $(this).serialize();
    
    $.post({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/api/pois/',
      data: formData
    })
```

```html
<form id="newForm">
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
  <input type="text" id="company" name="company">
</form>
    
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" form="newForm" id="confirmYes">Save</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because you are creating a new `submit` event handler in every click. From the description of what you want to do, you instead need to create a single submit handler when the page loads, and trigger it when the button is clicked. Something like this:

```js
$('#newForm').submit(function(e) { // handle the submit event
  e.preventDefault();
  let formData = $(this).serialize();

  $.post({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/api/pois/',
    data: formData
  })
})

$('#confirmYes').click(function() {
  $('#confirm-object').modal('hide');
  $('#newForm').submit(); // trigger the submit event
});
```

Comment: Thank you this work as I was hoping for! Thank you for pointing out my mistakes and give an explanation of what happened before, much appreciated. 
Still not quite got my head around how the submit handler is created, but then I just got back from my regular work and need to clear my head. Will do some more studying on this =).

Comment: Oh yeah, this make a lot more sense now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Simply remove the `$('#newForm').submit(function (e) {});` :

`.submit(function (e) {})` is creating an event handler for the `submit` event of your form, it's not submitting it.

```
$('#confirmYes').click(function() {
  $('#confirm-object').modal('hide'); // close confirm modal

  let formData = $('#newForm').serialize();

  $.post({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/api/pois/',
    data: formData
  });
});
```

Comment: I tried this example and it did not actually submit any form, not sure why. Would it be the save button has a type="submit"? However, I changed it to regular button and that did not make a difference. @Roy McCrossan's example worked though. Will try and understand the difference.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#confirmYes').click(function() {

  let formData = $('#newForm').serialize();
  $.post({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/api/pois/',
  data: formData
});
);
```

```html
<form id="newForm">
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
  <input type="text" id="company" name="company">
</form>
    
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="confirmYes">Save</button>
</div>
```